# Php sendgrid Path issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, sendgrid

I am using the CodeIgniter framework to build my application. I want to use the SendGrid library downloaded externally in my project. The problem is I don't know how to refer (load) that file in view and controller.

My folder structure for the SendGrid library is  `root>application>library>sendgrid>` for view is `root>application>view>filename.php` of dependency of sendgrid. Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$this->load->library('email');`

Refer to the Sendgrid doc [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/codeigniter/)

Comment: Thanks for help its works,but I need to send html content with that how can i achieve that